# Strong power for a treatment size within the 95% confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, statistical-power

I have a set of country-specific RD regression results showing very wide confidence intervals for my point estimates. The regressione are conducted through the local polynomial approach described by Cattaneo, M. D., Idrobo, N., and Titiunik, R. (2019). Cattaneo et al. also developed an ex-post statistical power test that provides power against specific treatment sizes, given the sample size. I am confused by the fact that I seem to have high statistical power against treatment sizes that are well within my confidence intervals. For example, I have a 95% CI of [-0.071, 0.066] and a power of 0.876 against a treatment size of 0.019. I am running the analysis in R with the rdrobust and rdpower packages developed by the authors.
I really don't know the reason for this. Are there possible explanations behind this?

Hope someboday can help me, thank in advance!